# Use jquery .before(); method in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to repeat a form element using jquery's .before(); method , so that users of the form can add more ingredients in this case to their recipe.

So far I have come up with this, however I cant use ruby code in a js file

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
  var ingredient = '<%= f.text_field :ingredients, :class => :ingred %><br>';
   $('#addIngredient').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $(this).before(ingredient);

   })
  });
```

I have done it using html5 and had it working doing this

```
   $('document').ready(function() {

            var ingredient = '<input class="ingredients" name="ingredients" type="text" placeholder="Enter Ingredients Here"><br>';
             $('#addingredient').click(function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
                $(this).before(ingredient);

                 })
               });
```

Im just having trouble getting this to fit in with my ruby form

at the moment i get this outputted to the page rather than the text field

```
     <%= f.text_field :ingredients, :class => :ingred %>
```

Can anyone help? Much appreciated

Comment: Could you show us the actual output of your template - the rendered page's JS code?

Comment: Seems like you have the code in a JS file right? I guess ruby won't compile it then. You'll most likely have to output that variable in a <script> tag in the page, either globally or in a namespace for it to be parsed then you can use it in your JS file.

Comment: how would i do that? apologies still learning

Comment: I'm not experienced with RoR either, but I'm assuming that's how it works as that's the pattern I use for PHP. This is a rather clunky solution but is the only one I can think of. Maybe someone can enlighten us with a better answer. `=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, this should be in a file in the `views` directory in your rails application (e.g. `/myrailsapp/app/views/<controllername>`) with an extension of .erb.

You can either have the code above wrapped in  `<script> </script>` tags in your view file called `<action>.html.erb` or in a partial e.g. `_beforeaction.js.erb` which you can then load into the main `<action>.html.erb` file using:

```
<%= render "beforeaction" %>
```

(Note: `<action>` is the action in your rails controller).

You can read the guides here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

http://ruby.about.com/od/rails3tutorial/ss/Getting-Started-With-Rails-Views.htm